# Batch code: use .txt file contents as file title

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a batch file that starts recording a video (through VLC) and saves the video file on the desktop with the title as the date and time, and the ID number of the current user, which is saved in a text file called "currentsubjectinfo.txt." Here's what I have so far:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"--qt-start-minimized dshow://--sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=1024,fps=30,width=1280,acodec=mp2a,ab=128,scale=1,channels=2,deinterlace,audio-sync}:standard{access=file,mux=ps,dst="C:\Users\User\Desktop\\subj-%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.mp4"}
```

This does everything I need except include the ID number in the file title, because I can't figure out how to get the batch to get the necessary info from the text file. So right now, the file is saved under a title like "subj-20141013-165213." I want it to instead say "subj1985-20141013-165213"

The text file with the user's ID number (currentsubjectinfo.txt) is found in a text file with the following information and formatting:

```
Subject   1985
Condition 1
```

Is there a way to get it to retrieve only the "1985" from this file and use it in the file title? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<"currentsubjectinfo.txt" set /p "subjectID=" 
for %%a in (%subjectID%) do set "subjectID=%%a"
echo %subjectID%
```

Read the first line in the file into a variable and for each value inside the variable store that value into the same variable.

A more verbose but more reliable way will be

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('
    find "Subject" ^< "currentsubjectinfo.txt"
') do set "subjectID=%%~a"

echo %subjectID%
```

Execute a `find` command searching the required line in the file, and retrieve the second line in the line into the variable

Comment: I only tried the 2nd, more verbose way but it works perfectly. Thanks!